# Interesting issue when attempting to reset pointer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Being that my C++ isn't that great, this may be a really simple/obvious answer, but it sure has me stumped. Keep in mind its kinda late here and I'm a little tired. I got this code here:

```
void TestFunc(int *pVar)
{
    cout << endl << *pVar << endl;
    delete pVar;
    pVar = nullptr;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int *z(new int);

    *z = 5;
    TestFunc(z);
    if (z == nullptr)
        cout << "z Successfully Deleted!" << endl;
    else cout << "z NOT deleted!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles just fine with no errors or warning. When I run it, it displays `5`, just as I'd expect. However, it says `z NOT deleted!`. I am curious as to why `pVar` is not getting set to `nullptr` even though I explicity set it in my TestFunc() function. Any help would be appreciated. If it matters, this is Visual Studio 2010 and just a regular unmanaged C++ application.

Comment: You just learned why it is a bad idea to delegate a pointer reset elsewhere. Good practice would be to delete the pointer in the same scope of code in which it was allocated. Even better - use smart pointers.

Comment: @littleadv - The code I pasted here was just a simplified example of the same issue I was having. The actual code that I have where this problem existed is calling a method in a class and by setting the pointer to `nullptr`, the calling function knows there is no more data to receive. If there is a better way to do this, I'm all for it.

Comment: @icemanid - yes, there is. Use flags to flag things, don't abuse parameters to pass information they were not designed to pass. Either use a return value for flags, or an additional parameter (passed by reference), and leave the pointer untouched to be released by the caller.

Comment: @littleadv - That is a good idea. Maybe I should make a method in my class such as `IsMoreData()` that returns a bool, rather then trying to manage the deallocation of pointers on my own.

Comment: @icemanid - that would be an elegant solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it's being **passed by value** (i.e. as a copy).

If you want the variable *itself* to be passed (rather than just its value, which is copied), use

```
void TestFunc(int *&pVar)
```

instead.

Note that `delete` only cares about the *pointee*, not the *pointer*. So "deleting" a copy of a pointer deletes the same thing as the original pointer, because in either case you're deleting their targets, which are the same.

Comment: Making this change, as you suggested made it work the way I'd expect. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`TestFunc` accepts the pointer by value, so setting it to null inside the function actually only affects the copy in the function and is not visible to the caller. So `pVar` is set to null, but `z` in `main()` is not because those are different variables.

To make the change visible to the caller pass the pointer by reference or via a double pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It is late (sorry!!!).

`z` is passed by value.  `z` is not `pVar`.  You assigned the value of `nullptr` to `pVar` and not to  `z`.

Comment: All is not well at all. z points to a memory which is no longer allocated to it.

Comment: You're correct of course.  I actually meant something like "all is well with your compiler and the fact that the OP did *not* see the message `"z Successfully Deleted"` means the program was interpreted as it was written.  Still your point is well taken and I should change the answer.

Comment: At the moment the procedure is called, pVar and z point to the same adress. The memory of z and pVar is freed but ONLY the variable pVar is set to NULL. The variable z in the main function remains unchanged. As mentioned in the previous comment. To access z after the procedure call will have unpredictable results. If you were lucky in an exception

Comment: Thanks Uhil.  I am going to claim "It *is* late" myself.  I wrote "deleted" when I meant (really :)) assigned-the-value-nullptr-which-you-checked-for.

Answer (score 0):

The "idiom" you present is generally advocated as *Safe Delete*.

It was already known in C (though it was a `free` back then): zero-out the pointer you just freed / deleted to avoid doing so twice.

The trouble is, you zero out the current **pointer**, but any copy of it still point to the same memory area, which now contains garbage.

Memory handling is a difficult topic, the fundamental concept is **ownership**. At any point in time, the owners of a particular memory zone should be well identified, and *they* should have the responsibility of returning it to the system when appropriate.

The first step in this direction is the use of smart pointers, for example `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`. For shared ownership (experts only), `std::shared_ptr` might come handy, but you're not there yet.

If you write a `delete` in your code, it means you are exposing yourself to leaks. It is not bad in itself, but it calls for careful review, and makes the code brittle (ie, likely to break on change). In your case:

```
int main() {
  boost::scoped_ptr<int> i(new 5);
  foo(*i);
} // memory returned to system by ~scoped_ptr()
```

Comment: So a "smart pointer", as you called it, like boost, would do automatic garbage collection, similar to how C# works maybe?

Comment: @icemanind: it is not garbage collection, but it's close. Garbage collection is much more clever, and covers the case of cycles of references. A smart pointer simply ties down the lifetime of the object it points to to a stack-based variable, making it similar to that of any other stack-based variable you are used to deal with.